# MySQL issue in Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am running the below and am getting the  error. Can anyone help?

```
import feedparser, MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='passsswd’, db=‘no’)
```

ERROR:

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-0238cde77faf>", line 2
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='passsswd’, db=‘no’)

^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: If you are using an IDE, I suggest setting-up syntax highlighting. You'll immediately see that the format of the `passwd=` value stays the same until `)`, hinting that something's wrong, even before you run your code (similar to how the code looks like here in SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `’` and `‘` instead of `'`, which confuses the interpreter. Just replace all instances of `’` and `‘` with `'`.